# toRight of is not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put 4 star in a line on the right of "Rate This Story". For that Iam using toRightof command in Linear layout,but don't know why its not working.And same problem is also occuring when Iam trying to put text on the right side of the image of a girl in the bottom of picture.

[image]

Here is my XML Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:background="@drawable/empty"
    tools:context=".story_activity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Story Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
       <!-- android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"-->/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:background="@drawable/story_des"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/lion"/>

</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This specification does not indicate the behavior, rendering or otherwise, of space characters other than those explicitly identified here as white space characters. For this reason, authors should use appropriate elements and styles to achieve visual formatting effects that involve white space, rather than space characters."
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:id="@+id/story_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/story_rate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rate This Story"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:textColor="#1e5aaa"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rate"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                android:src="@drawable/star"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rate1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate"

                android:src="@drawable/star"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rate2"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate1"
                android:src="@drawable/star"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rate3"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate2"
                android:src="@drawable/star"
                />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/line"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/author_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_line"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/as" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author_image"
        android:fontFamily="century-gothic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_line"
        android:text="Author Title"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pub_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/author_title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:fontFamily="century-gothic"
        android:text="Pve sentences, cjajsxa "
        />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `toRight`  is work with `Relative layout` not with `LinearLayout`

Comment: `toRight` will work only in `RelativeLayout`. If you are using `LinearLayout` then you can use `android:gravity` or `android:layout_gravity`. Also you can set `weight` to your layout to that it will be on right side

Comment: Thanku but it also work in Linear layout all I have to do is use another linear layout inside parent layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to embed your `imageViews` inside another `linearLayout` that have an `horizontal` `orientation`, something like this:

```
          <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal">
               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/rate"
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/star"
                   />
               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/rate1"
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate"

                   android:src="@drawable/star"
                   />
               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/rate2"
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate1"
                   android:src="@drawable/star"
                   />
               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/rate3"
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate2"
                   android:src="@drawable/star"
                   />
           </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanku its working, but we have to give weight to this linear layout as Iam using weight_sum property and also put the Text view of Rate This Story in the same Layout